# Prevent scrolling on mobile on page with canvas

Tags: javascript, ios, css, mobile, vertical-scrolling

I've tried many solutions online, but for some reason, this page still moves around vertically when moving my touch on the canvas:

```
<html>  
<head>
<style>

html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  background-color: lightgray;
  position: relative;
}

body.noScroll { 
  overflow: hidden;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" style="touch-action: none;" width="800" height="800"></canvas><br>        

        <script>

            document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", getTouchPos)

            var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas')            
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d')   

            context.fillStyle = "#000";
            context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            function getTouchPos(evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
            }

        </script>   
    </body> 
</html>
```

Tested on iOS Safari.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you found this post yet?
[Disable scroll/swipe action for html canvas drawing on ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49047414/disable-scroll-swipe-action-for-html-canvas-drawing-on-ios?rq=1)

It led to the following link. Looks like there are multiple events you have to account for. you have to reference your canvas as a dom element as well to evaluate the target

http://bencentra.com/code/2014/12/05/html5-canvas-touch-events.html

Comment: Thanks, adding preventDefault on the other touch events seems to work.