# how to launch a webpage on mobile web application without scroll

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mobile

EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION:

**What I want:**

A full screen javascript canvas which can handle touch events without those events being further interpreted by the browser, but also reserve the ability to open a new window on user action.

**Examples:**

- I should be able to swipe my finger around without the webpage trying to scroll
- I should be able to swipe my finger around without the contents of the webpage being nudged in any way (normally, when one scrolls to the end of a scroll region, the browser allows some additional spring-loaded buffer scrolling to signal to the user that it is the end of the scroll region).
- I should be able to pinch and pan without the webpage zooming
- etc...

**The point:**

I need to interpret these events accurately and in realtime MYSELF to respond to these actions WITHIN THE CANVAS. (I am doing realtime drawing via `requestAnimationFrame`, allowing me to react to user events without using the DOM)

**The state of things currently:**

This all works perfectly (*except for the ability to open a new window*) because I position the canvas to be the full size of the viewport (handling any window resize events), and the canvas listens to `ontouchstart`, `ontouchmove`, `ontouchend`, etc... events, calling `evt.preventDefault()` after I have handled the user input myself. This works to ensure the canvas is ALWAYS full screen, doesn't budge, and user input is accurately given to me to handle in-game.

**The Problem:**

One bit of user input I need to handle is the launching of a webpage when they click the region of my canvas with a "launch my webpage" button. However, `window.open(mywebpage)` doesn't work, because mobile safari only allows such an action in the callstack of a `click` event. Because I rely on `ontouchstart` to get responsive controls, and `evt.preventDefault()` in an `ontouchstart` event CANCELS the `click` event from happening, I cannot launch the webpage (it gets blocked by the browser).

**My attempted solutions, and why they are insufficient:**

- Just use a click event rather than ontouchstart: this means I can't prevent scrolling/etc... additionally, it is not as responsive, and doesn't allow me to handle touch-and-drag events well.
- Overlay a `div` (or an `a`) tag atop the canvas over the launch webpage zone, and add a click event to that: if the user clicks-and-drags *starting within this tag*, then it allows the page to scroll and zoom. Trying to fix this results in the same problem as before.

---

ORIGINAL POST:

I have a mobile application that is a full-screen canvas, which locks itself positionally (can't scroll or zoom) so that I can correctly interpret user input uninterrupted (swipes, pans, etc...).

It locks itself in by intercepting `touchstart` events and calling `evt.preventDefault` (as well as the meta viewport no-zoom stuff which as far as I can tell doesn't actually do anything?).

This works great, and is absolutely necessary to make a game (or game-like application) function.

The problem is that I also have a "go to this webpage" button. I can intercept the `touchstart`, and use `window.open(somewebpage)`, but mobile popup blockers will block it. The "rules" seem to be "the webpage will be allowed to be opened iff it is done in the call stack of a user interaction, AND that interaction is a 'click' event".

I have the first part down, but if I change the event to a `click` event, the web page now interprets swipes as scrolls (and pinches as zooms, etc...). If I have both a `click` and a `touchstart` event, then calling `evt.preventDefault()` on the `touchstart` (which stops the scroll/zoom) also stops the `click` event.

If I overlay a `div` atop the click zone of the "launch webpage" button, then the player can scroll/zoom *when their input begins in that button*, which results in an unpredictable and wonky experience.

How can I launch another webpage without allowing the current webpage to scroll?

Edit: at request, here is a code snippet at least partially illustrating what I'm trying to do https://jsfiddle.net/phildo/0q8e47fk/10/.
Note that in the "real" case, the canvas takes up the full width/height of the screen, and is explicitly set accordingly on screen resize.

Comment: For starters, having a page the size of the viewport prevents scrolling, as there's nothing to scroll to.  And for having a button as a link... I'd recommend simply making a link `<a>` and styling it as you need, so the browser can handle it.  If these things don't apply to your situation... I'm not sure I'm understanding your question.  An example on JSFiddle or something, demonstrating the problem, would be helpful.

Comment: Without code, we can only guess. An answer would only be as good as how the question is asked, a bounty won't help much if you don't help us help you.

Comment: I have added example code.
And @Brad- that is not the case that being the size of the viewport prevents scrolling. Mobile web browsers do the whole "spring-y boundaries" that lets you push around the contents if you don't explicitly call evt.preventDefault in ontouchstart.
I assume the <a> solution will have the exact problem as the <div> problem (which is that, if I'm not calling evt.preventDefault on the touchstart of THAT element, it will allow the same scrolling. If I AM calling that, it won't be triggered on a click. If it isn't triggered on a click, it's blocked by the popup blocker)

Comment: Please include the button you want to allow click for in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preventing bounces of any kind on mobile web page is a vast problem through out the mobile devices not depending about the manufacturer. I had similar issue on Windows Phone 8 app years ago and there (quite surprisingly) was a solution dedicated to Windows environment which of course cannot applied here.

For iOS you need an iOS solution, right?

The very solution is named `iNoBounce`. The idea is to add the little `js` library to your html page, code with some good conventions and the `js` lib will do the dirty job of preventing the default when necessary.

The trick it actually does is not to prevent just anything, but the ones only, that are "extra" and will cause the bounce events.

With the words of `iNoBounce` GitHub Readme:

> `iNoBounce` detects if the browser supports `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` by checking for the property on a fresh `CSSStyleDeclaration`. If it does, `iNoBounce` will listen to `touchmove` and selectively `preventDefault()` on `move` events that don't occur on a child of an element with `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` set. In addition, `iNoBounce` will `preventDefault()` when the user is attemping to scroll past the bounds of a `scrollable` element, preventing rubberbanding on the element itself (an unavoidable caveat).

The example code asks you to use the following parts (there is a separate example code for canvas, this is only the most common solution):

```
// All you need is an element with `height` or `max-height`, `overflow: auto` and `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`.

<script src="inobounce.js"></script>

<style>
    ul {
        height: 115px;
        border: 1px solid gray;
        overflow: auto;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
</style>
```

**Source:**

[1] https://github.com/lazd/iNoBounce

**Edit:**

I found out you did not limit yourself to iOS. For other browsers, try

[2] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior

which introduces `overscroll-behavior` setting, that you can set to `none` to disable bounces.

It will work only on Android, not ie or iOS.

For mobile Windows Phone I had the solution like this:

```
  div.wp8ScrollFix {
         -ms-touch-action: none;
   }
```

which effectively does the same as iNoBounce, now with single CSS line for the div containing the canvas.

**Edit2:**

For a search of semi universal solution, I could find that

```
  -touch-action: none;
```

applied to div element that includes the canvas, you can disable default touch events and for the canvas, define your own.

The solution works on any other than Safari browsers. As in [3] there may be some variants like

```
   -ms-touch-action: none;
```

but I suppose they are now all same without prefixes. The [3] solution is very old and world has changed a lot from those days.

The sad thing is, the browser support is same at least 2019 [4] and maybe now also.

**Sources:**

[3] [jQuery / HTML5 / gwt app for WP8 (Lumia 920) device: vertical css scroll fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943291/jquery-html5-gwt-app-for-wp8-lumia-920-device-vertical-css-scroll-fix)

[4] https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/touch-action/

Comment: I'm sad to hear that the problem requires such a bloated solution, but appreciate that someone actually addressed the concern. mobile javascript developers should be rioting in the streets. I hope that you (or someone else) will update this answer should a more standard solution become available. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have to take a look. Maybe an android + windows solution could be found to ease this a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

Show a div on top of full screen canvas element that intercepts normal click events on element canvas.

## Solution

Aside from click events, you need to intrrcept the following touch events:

- touchstart
- touchend
- touchmove
- touchcancel

### Additional Info

You only `preventDefault` on the canvas events so you should still be able to create a clickable/touchable element in the canvas that shows a div outside the canvas positioned with  a `z-index` higher than the canvas element by setting on `display: block` on the div. The div should also have `100vh` and `100vw` set foe width and height respectively and be `position: fixed`. The div should also have a button to hide again `display: none`.

## References

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51127296/806876

Comment: I've added some example code above. I'm not sure what you mean by "full screen pop under". I do edit the width/height of my canvas to perfectly match the viewport of my screen on window resize.
My situation is that I have a webpage which consists of nothing but a full-page canvas. To allow for interaction atop that canvas, I have to evt.preventDefault on touchstart (otherwise, the mobile browsers will allow the user to nudge the page contents). This disallows click events. I can't launch a page from anything but a click event. There are no pop ups, pop unders, etc...

Comment: @Phildo Thanks for clarifying. I’ve updated my answer. You already are intercepting click and touchstart, scrolling is occurring because you never intercepted touchmove. I also explain what to do if you want a div overlay aka “popunder” above your canvas, which I’m assuming you want for the “Launch Webpage” button—otherwise I can remove that explanation under additional info.

Comment: your stated problem is not the problem I'm interested in, nor the one I stated, nor the one illustrated in the example code. I will edit my above question to be more clear.